# Cannot resolve SetImageResource

Tags: imageview

I have this code

```
package com.kmsmartapps.test5;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void clickIM(View view) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imview);
        image.SetImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Android studio shows error : 
Error:(11, 14) error: cannot find symbol method SetImageResource(int)
I want to change the source image using a button. With android studio 2.3 it worked fine but now using android studio 3.0 it doesn't work. 
I tried solutions proposed in this forum but still showing error.
Can you tell how to fix this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was an error writing SetImageResource. I must write it with small s like this setImageResource. When changing to small the problem was resolved.